# How do I set an env variable in PowerShell if it doesn't exist?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I'm surprised that I didn't get the answer for this common scenario after Googling for while...

How can an environment variable in be set in PowerShell if it does not exist?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The following code defines environment variable `FOO` for the current process, if it doesn't exist yet.

```bash
if ($null -eq $env:FOO) { $env:FOO = 'bar' }

# If you want to treat a *nonexistent* variable the same as
# an existent one whose value is the *empty string*, you can simplify to:
if (-not $env:FOO) { $env:FOO = 'bar' }

# Alternatively, via the Env: *drive*:
if (-not (Test-Path env:FOO)) { $env:FOO = 'bar' }

# Or even (quietly fails if the variable already exists):
New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore env:FOO -Value bar
```

In *PowerShell (Core) 7.1+*, which has [null-coalescing operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#null-coalescing-assignment-operator-), you can simplify to:

```bash
$env:FOO ??= 'bar'
```

<sup>Note:

Environment variables are *strings* by definition. If a given environment variable is *defined*, but *has no value*, its value is the *empty string* (`''`) rather than `$null`. Thus, comparing to `$null` can be used to distinguish between an *undefined* environment variable and one that is *defined, but has no value*. However, note that *assigning* to environment variables *in PowerShell / .NET* makes *no* distinction between `$null` and `''`, and *either* value results in *undefining (removing)* the target environment variable; similarly, in `cmd.exe` `set FOO=` results in removal/non-definition of variable `FOO`, and the GUI dialog (accessible via `sysdm.cpl`) doesn't allow you to define a variable with an empty string either. However, the Windows API ([`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable)) *does* permit creating environment variables that contain the empty string, albeit in-process only.

On Unix-like platforms, empty-string values are allowed too, and the native, POSIX-compatible shells (e.g, `bash` and `/bin/sh`) - unlike PowerShell - *also* allow you to create them (e.g, `export FOO=`). Note that environment variable definitions and lookups are case-*sensitive* on Unix, unlike on Windows.

This design limitation of the .NET APIs - as of .NET 8 - has been reported in [GitHub issue #95559](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/95559)</sup>

Note: If the environment variable is created on demand by the assignment above (`$env:FOO = ...`), it will exist for the **current process** and any *child processes* it creates **only** <sup>Thanks, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)</sup>.

---

<sup>The following was mostly contributed by [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers), with a supplement by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):</sup>

**On *Windows***<sup>[*]</sup>, if you want to **define an environment variable *persistently***, you need to use the static [`SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) method of the [`[System.Environment]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment) class:

```bash
# user environment
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FOO', 'bar', 'User')

# system environment (requires admin privileges)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FOO', 'bar', 'Machine')
```

Note that these definitions take effect in *future* sessions (processes), so in order **to define the variable for the *current* process *as well***, run `$env:FOO = 'bar'` *in addition*, which is effectively the same as `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FOO', 'bar', 'Process')`.

<sup>When using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` with `User` or `Machine`, a [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message is sent to other applications to notify them of the change (though few applications react to such notifications).

This doesn't apply when targeting `Process` (or when assigning to `$env:FOO`), because no other applications (processes) can see the variable anyway.</sup>

See also: [Creating and Modifying Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730964(v=technet.10)) (TechNet article).

---

<sup>[*] On **Unix**-like platforms, attempts to target the *persistent* scopes - `User` or `Machine`- are *quietly ignored*, as of .NET (Core) 7, and this **non-support for defining persistent environment variables** is unlikely to change, given the lack of a unified mechanism across Unix platforms.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
function Set-LocalEnvironmentVariable {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Name,

        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Value,

        [Parameter()]
        [Switch]
        $Append
    )

    function Write-MyMessage {
        param(
            [System.String]
            $VarName
        )
        WWrite-Host "Local Environment variable " -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -NoNewline
        Write-Host "`"$VarName`"" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "  ➡  " -ForegroundColor DarkYellow -NoNewline
        try {
            Write-Host "`"$((Get-Item env:$VarName).Value)`"" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host """""" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }

    if ($Append.IsPresent) {
        if (Test-Path "env:$Name") {
            $Value = (Get-Item "env:$Name").Value + $Value
        }
    }
    New-Item env:$Name -Value "$value" -Force | Out-Null
    if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose.IsPresent) {
        Write-MyMessage -VarName $Name
    }
}

function Set-PersistentEnvironmentVariable {
    param (
        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Name,
    
        [Parameter()]
        [System.String]
        $Value,
    
        [Parameter()]
        [Switch]
        $Append        
    )
    
    function Write-MyMessage {
        param(
            [System.String]
            $VarName
        )
        Write-Host "Persistent Environment variable " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
        Write-Host "`"$VarName`"" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "  ➡  " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
        try {
            Write-Host "`"$((Get-Item env:$VarName).Value)`"" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host """""" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }

    Set-LocalEnvironmentVariable -Name $Name -Value $Value -Append:$Append
    if ($Append.IsPresent) {
        $value = (Get-Item "env:$Name").Value
    }
    if ($IsWindows) {
        setx "$Name" "$Value" | Out-Null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose.IsPresent) {
            Write-MyMessage -VarName $Name
        }
        return
    }
    if ($IsLinux -or $IsMacOS) {
        $pattern = "\s*export\s+$name=[\w\W]*\w*\s+>\s*\/dev\/null\s+;\s*#\s*$Name\s*"
        $files = @("~/.bashrc", "~/.zshrc", "~/.bash_profile", "~/.zprofile")
        
        $files | ForEach-Object {
            if (Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf) {
                $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$(Resolve-Path $_)")
                $content = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($content, $pattern, [System.Environment]::NewLine);
                $content += [System.Environment]::NewLine + "export $Name=$Value > /dev/null ;  # $Name" + [System.Environment]::NewLine
                [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$(Resolve-Path $_)", $content)
            }
            
        }
        if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose.IsPresent) {
            Write-MyMessage -VarName $Name
        }
        return
    }
    
    throw "Invalid platform."
}
```

---

- **function Set-PersistentEnvironmentVariable**
  Set a variable/value in actual process and system. This function calls Set-LocalEnvironmentVariable function to set process scope variables and perform task for set variables in machine scope.

On Windows you can use:

- **[[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_)** with machine scope, user or machine don't work on Linux or MacOS
- **[setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx)** command

On Linux we can add **export VARIABLE_NAME=Variable value** to file **~/.bash_profile**. For a new bash terminal the process execute these instructions located in **~/.bash_profile**.

On MacOS similiar to Linux but if you have **zsh terminal** the file is **.zprofile**, if the default terminal is **bash**, the file is **.bash_profile**. In my function code we need to add detection of default terminal if you wish. I assume that default terminal is **zsh**.

- **function Set-LocalEnvironmentVariable**
  Set a variable/value in actual process. Using Drive **env:**.

---

**Examples**

```
#Set "Jo" value to variable "NameX", this value is accesible in current process and subprocesses, this value is accessible in new opened terminal.
Set-PersistentEnvironmentVariable -Name "NameX" -Value "Jo"; Write-Host $env:NameX

#Append value "ma" to current value of variable "NameX", this value is accesible in current process and subprocesses, this value is accessible in new opened terminal.
Set-PersistentEnvironmentVariable -Name "NameX" -Value "ma" -Append; Write-Host $env:NameX

#Set ".JomaProfile" value to variable "ProfileX", this value is accesible in current process/subprocess.
Set-LocalEnvironmentVariable "ProfileX" ".JomaProfile"; Write-Host $env:ProfileX
```

---

**Output**

**Windows 10**
[image: Windows]

**Ubuntu WSL**
[image: Ubuntu - Linux]

---

**References**

Check [About Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_)
[Shell initialization files](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)
[ZSH: .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin - What goes where?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/zsh-zprofile-zshrc-zlogin-what-goes-where)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to set an environment variable in PowerShell if it doesn't exist:

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path Env:VAR_NAME)) {
    New-Item -Path Env:VAR_NAME -Value "VAR_VALUE"
}
```

Replace VAR_NAME with the name of the environment variable and VAR_VALUE with the desired value.