# Epicor 10 DMT Tool Command Line Arguments

Tags: powershell, epicorerp, epicor10

What is the command line flag to set the Environment in the Epicor DMT Tool?
Running the powershell script below results in the DMT tool selecting the default database (live in this case). Setting the server with the "-server" flag did cause the DMT tool to connect to the correct environment either. Thanks.

```
$DMTPath = ""
$Server = ""
$Port = ""

#Set UI (0 = no ui, !0 = ui)
$ui=0
$User = ""
$Pass = ""

$Env = ""
$Path = "filepath

$Import = @("","")

$File = @("","")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $Import.length; $i++){

    $Source = $Path + $File[$i]
    echo "Loading... " 
    $Import[$i]
    echo "$Source"

    $Args = "-User $User -Pass $Pass -Add=true -Update=true -Import $Import[$i] -Source $Source "

    if($ui -eq 0){ $Args = $Args + " -noui"}

    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $DMTPath -ArgumentList $Args
}

echo "Process complete, confirm uploads are correct"
```

Comment: Your question is "find me a command line parameter for epicor DMT"? Or is it "how do I set an environment variable in powershell?" (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928342/how-to-set-an-env-variable-in-powershell-if-it-doesnt-exist )

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, my question is what is the command line parameter, I was googling around for quite a while and could not find much documentation on the DMT tool .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing `DMT.exe /?` will display help for running DMT from the command line.

I assume by environment you mean which of the instances i.e. pilot, test, live etc that you want to connect to. This is done as part of the `ConnectionUrl`:

```
DMT.exe -ConnectionUrl=”net.tcp://localhost/Live” -Import=”Part” -Source=”C:\Imports\Part.csv” -Add=True -Update=True -user=manager -pass=manager
```

You can get the connection url from a .sysconfig file in the client config folder.

You may want to log on to and search http://epicweb.epicor.com for more documentation.