# Set path where PowerShell tries to find applications

Tags: powershell

Months ago, Sqlite3 was setup on a .NET development machine in an effort to develop an application that will run PowerShell scripts to build/rebuild an offline DB.  On the development machine, everything works perfectly.  The deployment for testing on a users machine has hit a roadblock.

Sqlite3 is installed to the C:\sqlite3 folder.  The PowerShell script is unable locate the "sqlite3" command that points to the "sqlite3.exe" located in the application folder.  Using PowerShell in .NET is new to me and I am unable to recall the steps from months ago for setting up PowerShell to run Sqlite3.

On the development system, the following is displayed via PowerShell:

[image]

On the user machine, I have been unable to determine how this command was setup so that PowerShell is able to recognize the command regardless of the current directory path.

Any wisdom is appreciated....thanks.

Comment: Always fully-qualify your paths.  `& 'C:\sqlite3\sqlite3.exe' args...`

Comment: Making a broad statement of qualifying paths has nothing to do with the issue at hand.  The question is how to configure PowerShell so that a command is recognized regardless of the current directory path....as shown in the image.

Comment: Fully-qualifying your path, as TheIncorrigible suggests, will configure Powershell to always recognize that command regardless of the current directory path.

Comment: Sqlite3 is a function for some reason in that picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When PowerShell looks for *external programs* specified by *file name only***,such as `sqlite3.exe` in your case:

- **It looks in the directories listed in `$env:Path`**, i.e., the `Path` environment variable, as preconfigured via the registry.

  - Note: This is how `cmd.exe` does it as well, except that it looks in the *current* directory first, which PowerShell by design doesn't do for security reasons.
- It invokes / reports the *first* executable by that name.

For inspection via `Get-Command` you can pass the `-All` switch to see if *multiple* executables by that name exist in `$env:Path`-listed directories, but for *invocation* it is always the *first* one that is used.

You therefore have 3 options:

- **Persistently modify the `Path` environment variable on the target machine** to include the `C:\sqlite3` directory, prior to invocation of your script.

  - Interactively, you can use Control Panel (specifically, `sysdm.cpl`, tab `Advanced`) to add to your `Path` variable, either in the current user's scope or the entire machine scope.
  - For programmatic manipulation via .NET, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928399/45375) (which could be combined with [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote) to perform the change remotely).
  - Use of [`reg.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg) is also an option, which itself supports targeting other machines; however, you must target the relevant registry paths explicitly in this case: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` (current user) and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` (local machine).
- Alternatively, **in your script**:

  - Either: **Invoke the executable by its *full path***, as [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) suggests:
    `C:\sqlite3\sqlite3.exe ...` (prepend `&` , if the path must be quoted or is specified via a variable).
  - Or: **Add `C:\sqlite3` to the `Path` variable before calling `sqlite3.exe`**:
    `$env:PATH += ';C:\sqlite3'` Note that this modified `Path` variable **will remain in effect for the entire PowerShell session (process), but will not persist**.

Comment: Nice.  I just found that also after adding in the  term "persistence" to my search.  Also, I was thinking that $env:path was the information that displays from the Windows environment variable PATH, however they are not the same.  On the development machine, the persistence statement you added had been done previously.  Since I was looking at the Windows PATH environment variable, C:\sqlite3 was not being displayed.  After reviewing the output from the PowerShell command "$env:path", I did see "C:\sqlite3" already listed.  Next step is to apply your persistence command on the users' machine

Comment: @Galactic: `$env:Path` is a combination of the current-user and local-machine environment-variable definitions in the registry that a process sees by default. Any process can modify the variable, which means that any child processes launched from it see the modification too. When you say _Windows PATH environment_ variable, what are you referring to? The registry-based definitions? If so, the current-user or the local-machine definition? Note that a potential source of `$env:Path` modification is your `$PROFILE` file, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script where I add the path for the jdk:

```
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine')

$list = $currentvalue -split ';'

# delete old one
$list = $list | where { $_ -notlike 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_*' }

# add new one
$list = $list + $args[0]

$newvalue = $list -join ';'

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $newvalue, 'Machine')

if ( -not $? ) { exit 1 }
```