# Cannot read environment variable set with PowerShell with os.environ.get

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables

A bit of a random problem here.  I set an environment variable using PowerShell like this:

```
$env:GOOGLE_ELEVATION_API="the_api-key"
```

Then in python I attempt to read it with this simple script:

```
from os import environ

key = environ.get("GOOGLE_ELEVATION_API")
```

This returns `None`.  If I query my environment variables in PowerShell it is there.  If I query it through python with `os.environ` it is not.

None of the results I found make reference that this should be an issue, neither on the PowerShell side nor on python's side.  I have not restarted my machine since I honestly do not believe this is what should be done.  I did restart my IDE in the hope that it is somehow caching the environment but thankfully it does not.

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: `$env:` <- only affects current runspace. Will you be running the scripts in the same user context, or do you need a machine-wide env var?

Comment: Ah.  Yes.  When I run this command from my PowerShell terminal in my IDE, it works.  But from a separate PSD window it does not.  What is the correct way to make a variable available machine wide?  (I guess I can look that up quickly as well.)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: environment variables exist at the _process_ level (try `$env:FOO = 'bar'; Start-ThreadJob { $env:FOO } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob` - perhaps that's what you meant, but note that a single process can host multiple PowerShell runspaces). A regularly invoked Python script would automatically inherit the calling PowerShell session's environment variables.

Comment: @mklement0 Ack, but I suspect it doesn't work exactly because `python` is not launched by powershell :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Setting an environment variable via PowerShell's `$env:` namespace defines it for the *current process only*.

  - Any Python scripts *invoked directly* from a PowerShell session *would* see such variables, however, because child processes *inherit* the caller's environment variables.
- To *persistently* define a Windows environment variable at the machine level that *all* processes see, you must use .NET APIs directly (as of PowerShell 7.4):

```bash
# Note: Requires ELEVATION, due to setting at the *machine* level.
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GOOGLE_ELEVATION_API', 'the_api-key', 'Machine')
```

Note that only *future* PowerShell sessions will see this variable,<sup>[1]</sup> and this need to *restart an application* in order for it to see the new variable *typically* also applies to other running applications.

(The exception are those applications that actively listen for the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message and refresh their environment in response, which is what the Windows GUI shell (`explorer.exe`) does.)

For more information about persistently setting environment variables on Windows, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928399/45375).

---

<sup>[1] However, you could define it for the current session too, by repeating the definition at the process level:

`$env:GOOGLE_ELEVATION_API = 'the_api-key'`</sup>